# How to get optimal size of custom component?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I have written a custom component:

```
public class ImageView extends JComponent {

    private BufferedImage mImage;

    public ImageView() {
        this(480, 320);
    }



    public ImageView(int width, int height) {
        mImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        clear();
    }



    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        mImage = image;
    }

    public void clear() {
        Graphics g = mImage.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        int x = (getWidth() - mImage.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - mImage.getHeight()) / 2;
        g.drawImage(mImage, x, y,this);
    }
}
```

But how can I initialize `mImage` with an optimal size to it was same size like my component if the user called default constructor?

Comment: Since the default constructor calls the width/height constructor and that creates the image, on which preferredSize bases it’s calculation on, I don’t see the issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer, my question is how to remove this constructor and initialize an image when I can get a real size of my component?.

Comment: The default size of the component is 0x0, you can “optimise” it by providing what ever “optimal” value you see fit through the width/height constructor. Defaulting the image size is your best approach

Comment: I see nothing in the custom component that could not be achieved (correctly & robustly) by using a Swing `JLabel`. Why does `ImageView` even exist?

Answer (score 1):

While your question is some what vague, I "think" this is along the path of what you're asking for...

```
public class ImageView extends JComponent {

    protected static final Dimension DEFAULT_SIZE = new Dimension(480, 320);
    private BufferedImage mImage;

    public ImageView() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public ImageView(int width, int height) {
        this();
        mImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        clear();
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        mImage = image;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (mImage == null) {
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = mImage.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return mImage == null ? DEFAULT_SIZE : new Dimension(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (mImage == null) {
            return;
        }
        //g.setColor(Color.white);
        //g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        int x = (getWidth() - mImage.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - mImage.getHeight()) / 2;
        g.drawImage(mImage, x, y,this);
    }
}
```

Basically, when `mImage` is `null` it returns a pre-define `DEFAULT_SIZE` of the component (as well as not painting the image)

> Nope, I wanna get a size that parent layout manager will set for my component. If my component is going to fill all available space that was provided by layout manager I wanna get a size of that space. I.e. I can set in a default constructor 300x300 image size but my component will have 400x300 because the layout manager allowed to fill bigger space. How can I get a size that my component will have really after start.

Until the component is physically laid out by the parent container, there's no way to know what size it will give it.  You could monitor changes to `setBounds`, but I tend to find `invalidate` a better choice (IMHO).

The problem, all these methods can be called a number of times in quick succession, so if you're performing operations which either take time or might require a largish amount of memory, it's best to use some kind of "delayed callback", forcing a required amount of time to have passed before you perform the required action.

I tend to use a Swing `Timer` to do this, it's simply and calls the `ActionListener` on the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within

```
public class ImageView extends JComponent {

    protected static final Dimension DEFAULT_SIZE = new Dimension(480, 320);
    private BufferedImage mImage;

    private  Timer invalidationTimer;

    public ImageView() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        invalidationTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stateInvalidated();
            }
        });
        invalidationTimer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public ImageView(int width, int height) {
        this();
        mImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate(); 
        invalidationTimer.restart();
    }

    protected void stateInvalidated() {
        System.out.println(getWidth() + "x" + getHeight());
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        mImage = image;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (mImage == null) {
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = mImage.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return mImage == null ? DEFAULT_SIZE : new Dimension(mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (mImage == null) {
            return;
        }
        //g.setColor(Color.white);
        //g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        int x = (getWidth() - mImage.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - mImage.getHeight()) / 2;
        g.drawImage(mImage, x, y, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, I wanna get a size that parent layout manager will set for my component. If my component is going to fill all available space that was provided by layout manager I wanna get a size of that space. I.e. I can set in a default constructor `300x300` image size but my component will have `400x300` because the layout manager allowed to fill bigger space. How can I get a size that my component will have really after start.

Comment: Until it's physically laid out you can't.  `invalidate` "might" provide you that information (by inspecting the `width`/`height` property), but it can be called several times in quick succession, so you might want to established a "delayed" notification